# Appium Mobile Web test automation Android for Twitter

Tags: android, selenium, automated-tests, appium, selendroid

I was making a test automator using Appium on a selenium server for my Android device. The automator launches the Twitter's webapp does a login and posts a Tweet. However, the part I'm having difficulty with is that the automator doesn't use the already logged in account on my Chrome browser. Why do I have to login every time? Is it because the session refreshes? Is there a way to avoid this?

My code:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;  
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class StartChrome
{
private String email="your_email";
private String password="your_password";
private WebDriver driver=null;
private int flag=0;

@BeforeTest
public void test1() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{

// Create object of  DesiredCapabilities class and specify android platform
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.android();


// set the capability to execute test in chrome browser
 capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,BrowserType.CHROME);

// set the capability to execute our test in Android Platform
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM,Platform.ANDROID);

// we need to define platform name
  capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");

// Set the device name as well (you can give any name)
 capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"my phone");

 // set the android version as well 
   capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION,"6.0.1");

 // Create object of URL class and specify the appium server address
 URL url= new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub");

// Create object of  AndroidDriver class and pass the url and capability that we created
 WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(url, capabilities);

// Open url
  driver.get("http://www.twitter.com");

 // print the title
  System.out.println("Title "+driver.getTitle());
    try{
  driver.findElement(By.id("react-root"));      
    }catch(Exception e){
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log in")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("session[username_or_email]")).sendKeys(email);
        driver.findElement(By.name("session[password]")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("signupbutton")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/compose/tweet']")).click();    
        flag=1;
    }
    finally{
        if(flag==0){
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/compose/tweet']")).click();    
            }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[aria-label*='Tweet text']")).sendKeys("Test");;
    //driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tweet")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-testid*='Button']")).click();


Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.quit();

}
```

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Twitter` session handles by setting client side [token cookies](http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/session-cookies-used-for.html). This token is hashcode composed commonly from your credentials and browser fingerprinting. Since `WebDriver` starts every time 'clear' browser, without cookies, of course - server doesn't recognize you and ask for authentication.

**Solutions:**

- Just accept this. Login every time. It looks as sane test-case. I would recommend this decision.
- Save token cookies `_twitter_sess`.

> ```
>   Cookie ck = new Cookie("_twitter_sess", "your_authorised_session_id");
>   driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
> ```

*Risks:* 1) This session cookie has expiration date. You will have to copypaste new `your_authorised_session_id` every morning. 2) It's possible that Twitter has tricky security system and they check [browser fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint)

- Use your existing `Chrome Profile`, it means your browser 'non clear one' that contains your history, your cookies. So you have to login to twitter manually right before running tests and it will persist.

> ```
> ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
> options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name<your_path_to_installed_chrome_in_mob_phone_in_your case>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/UserData");
> driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
> ```

Comment: Thanks! That actually makes sense! I'll try this out